# how do I get an Icecast stream metadata using aiohttp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp, icecast

I have been already searching for this before and only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876454), which does what I want with `requests`.

So, this is my initial code:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("http://myurl.com/mystream", headers={'Icy-MetaData': "1"}, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()
headers, stream = response.headers, response.raw
meta_int = headers.get('icy-metaint')
audio_length = int(meta_int)
audio_data = stream.read(audio_length)
meta_byte = stream.read(1)
if (meta_byte):
    meta_length = ord(meta_byte) * 16
    meta_data = stream.read(meta_length)
    print(meta_data)
```

, which I turned into `aiohttp` by myself:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://myurl.com/mystream", headers={'Icy-MetaData': "1"}) as response:
            headers = response.headers
            meta_int = headers.get('icy-metaint')
            audio_length = int(meta_int)
            meta_byte = await response.content.read(1)
            if (meta_byte):
                meta_length = ord(meta_byte) * 16
                meta_data = await response.content.read(meta_length)
                print(meta_data)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

, but it doesn't work.

When I use the `requests` one it does exactly what I need (get the stream title).
Instead, when I use the `aiohttp` one I get other data, which I can't decode to UTF-8, because it raises `invalid start byte`. I read every single letter of it, there is no trace of metadata.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Which line gives you the error? Does reading the first `audio_length` bytes like you do with requests make a difference?

Comment: @dirn Oh, I thought it was useless because it wasn't used in the code, but that fixed my problem. Thank you!